# python module imports itself instead of dist module

Tags: python

I have a python module named mimetypes that is relative to libx.something.  This mimetypes module wraps the python mimetypes module, but only in the case that the magic module isn't present.  However, when my application imports 'libx.something.mimetypes' and that module then imports 'mimetypes', it imports itself, relative to 'libx.something'.

How do I force import to work relative to the python dist path instead of the current module path, so that I can import the python mimetypes module?

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/libx/something/mimetypes.py", line 16, in get
    return mimetypes.guess_type(path)
Error: 'module' object has no attribute 'guess_type'
```

But...

```
$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Aug  1 2012, 05:16:07) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import mimetypes
>>> mimetypes.guess_type('a.txt')
('text/plain', None)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
```

in your `libx.something.mimetypes` module, or give it a different name.

See [PEP 328 - Imports: Multi-Line and Absolute/Relative](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/) for the nitty gritty details. In Python 2, imports are first resolved relative to the current module, before searching the modules path; with the above statement imports are *always* absolute unless you use the new relative import syntax (`from . import mimetypes`, etc.).

The statement switches import behaviour *per module*; adding it to your `libx.something.mimetypes` module will not alter behaviour of importing in other modules.